# typeOrm does not create entries in schema

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am using nestjs with typeOrm with Postgresql.
I am looking to save all data from the app in a different schema to 'public' as this is well known.
I have schema specified in an options file as below:

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
type: 'postgres',
host: 'localhost',
port: 5432,
username: 'xxxx',
password: 'xxx',
database: 'taskmanagement',
autoLoadEntities: true,
synchronize: true,
schema: 'sh',
};
```

I create the task as below:

```
async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
// create directly using the entity
const { title, description } = createTaskDto;
const task = new Task();
task.title = title;
task.description = description;
task.status = TaskStatus.OPEN;
await task.save();

return task;
}
```

The Task entity is defined as:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

import { TaskStatus } from './task-status.enum';

@Entity()
export class Task extends BaseEntity {
// @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
// id: string;

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;
@Column()
title: string;

@Column()
description: string;

@Column()
status: TaskStatus;
}
```

The record is saved to the schema 'public', not my custom schema 'sh'.

I would expect typeOrm to use the schema from the config given that it writes to DB specified in the config options file.

Is this a bug with nestjs/typeOrm or am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 0):

Run build script - this seems to get the revised config file to be used.